# How to copy All Documents from Document Library to Document set

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I have 2 Document Libraries Doc-A & Doc-B.I want to copy all Document from Document Library to Data set of Document Library-B. Using workflow & rest API.

Comment: Is this a one off task or are you looking for this to happen as items are added to Doc-A? Why do you specifically want to do this using REST?

Comment: then is any other way to achieve this task.

Comment: That depends on the version of SharePoint. It also depends if it is a one off task. If it is use PS if not and it is on item added you could use a workflow or an event receiver. There are various options but you need to give a little more detail on your requirements.

Comment: I want to do this task in sharepoint online.In sharepoint online Event receiver is not supported.

Comment: Yes, but you are missing the point. What do you actually want to achieve? Is this a one off copy for the current library or do you want items moved on addition? Does it have to be instant? A little more detail would help a lot...

Comment: In SharePoint online I have 2 Document Library.& I want to copy all Documents of 1st Document Library to Document set which is available in 2nd Document Library.

Comment: I want to move documents from one Library to another in a specific document set and this will be happen on the record insertion action on one list where we are selecting some documents (in a SP app/or any form) from the document library where all documents are stored and by using a normal copy action in SPD WF  we can not copy multiple documents so the rest api is one of that thing which could full fill my requirements,and with the rest api i can get and put any document to any destination effortlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly Refer [This](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201270/unable-to-copy-all-documents-from-one-library-to-another/201798#201798) for copying All Documents from Document Library to another library in Document set/Folder